# Show name of a trace on scatterpolar chart all the time without needing to hover over it

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to have the name of a Python plotly scatterpolar trace to always be visible, rather than having to hover over each trace on the graph. This is what I have so far in terms of code.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

categories = ['Passing', 'Dribbling', 'Shooting', 'Defense', 'Fitness']

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_traces(go.Scatterpolar(
    r=[6.33, 3.71, 0, 5.45, 5],
    theta=categories,
    fill='toself',
    name='Team Average'
))

fig.add_traces(go.Scatterpolar(
    r=[9.38, 2.86, 0, 5.0, 5.6],
    theta=categories,
    fill='toself',
    name='Player Average'
))

fig.update_layout(
    polar=dict(
        radialaxis=dict(
            visible=False,
            range=[0,10]
        )
    ),
    showlegend=False
)

fig.show()
```

And this is what the current scatterpolar chart looks like when I run it. As you can see, it does not show the names of each of the traces, and only appears when I hover over each trace.
[image]

Comment: Where do you want the names of the traces to display? Do you want them near the traces, or somewhere else on the plot? Either way, you can display the name(s) as [text annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/). I would be happy to explain further in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `go.Scatterpolar` chart, text annotations are difficult because you will need to specify the cartesian x- and y-coordinates for the text annotations. Polar coordinates for text annotations inside the chart are [not yet available](https://community.plotly.com/t/adding-annotations-to-polar-scatterplots/704/5), at least according to the linked Plotly forum post. While you could convert the polar coordinates of each point to x- and y-coordinates, and then add text at each of these locations, this seems like a heavy handed solution unless it's really necessary.

One compromise would be to use `px.line_polar` to draw the chart, and use the `text` argument to specify what text gets added for each point. Unfortunately you can only choose one field from your data (in your case, you can choose to display the value that you are passing to parameter `r`, or the category that you are passing to parameter `theta`).

To make px.line_polar look like go.Scatterpolar, you will want to add filling between the lines. In addition, to add the second px.line_polar chart on top of the first one, you'll need to create a new figure, then add that figure's data as a trace. You will also need to manually specify the color of the second px.line_polar chart.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

categories = ['Passing', 'Dribbling', 'Shooting', 'Defense', 'Fitness']

fig = go.Figure()

fig = px.line_polar(
    {'Team Average':[6.33, 3.71, 0, 5.45, 5], 'direction':categories}, 
    r="Team Average", 
    theta="direction", 
    start_angle=360,
    line_close=True,
    text="Team Average",
)

fig2 = px.line_polar(
    {'Player Average':[9.38, 2.86, 0, 5.0, 5.6], 'direction':categories}, 
    r="Player Average", 
    color_discrete_sequence=["salmon"]*5,
    theta="direction",
    start_angle=360, 
    line_close=True,
    text="Player Average",
)

## add fig2 to fig
fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0])

fig.update_traces(textposition='top center', fill='toself')

fig.update_layout(
    polar=dict(
        radialaxis=dict(
            visible=False,
            range=[0,10]
        )
    ),
    showlegend=False
)

fig.show()
```

[image]